# Why does font awesome icon rotate back to original position when using :hover to scale its size?

Tags: css, font-awesome, css-transforms

I'm making an image slider on my site. I have two FA arrow icons on each side. They're both rotated 90 degrees to point outward. I also have a `:hover` pseudo class on each one of them to scale the size when hovered. However while this will scale the size, it will also rotate the arrow back where it has started. Why is this, I can't seem to find a solid answer.

```js
const ham = document.querySelector('.nav-box');
const menu = document.querySelector('.menu');
const menuClose = document.querySelector('#menu-close');

ham.addEventListener('click', function() {
 ham.classList.add('ham-open');
 menu.style.marginLeft = '50px';
})

menuClose.addEventListener('click', function() {
 ham.classList.remove('ham-open');
 menu.style.marginLeft = '-700px';

})




window.sr = ScrollReveal();;

sr.reveal('.info', {
 duration: 2000,
 origin: 'bottom';
})
```

```css
html, body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

.header {
 background: url(img/mex-9.jpg);
 width: 100vw;
 height: 100vh;
 background-size: cover;
 background-attachment: fixed;
 background-position: center;
 display: flex;
}

.nav-wrap {
 flex-basis: 40%;
}

.nav-wrap i {
 color: white;
 font-size: 2rem;
 position: absolute;
 right: -33px;
 top: 0px;
 transition: all .1s ease;
}

.nav-wrap i:hover {
 cursor: pointer;
 transform: scale(1.15);
}

.nav-box {
 margin-left: 50px;
 margin-top: 100px;
 max-width: 70px;
 cursor: pointer;
 position: fixed;
}

.b1, .b2, .b3 {
 width: 70px;
 height: 8.5px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 background-color: #fff;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 transition: all .25s ease;
}

.b1 {
 background-color: #56ff47;
}

.b3 {
 background-color: #ff4c4c;
}

.ham-open .b1 {
 background-color: #56ff47;
 transform: translateY(100px);
 position: relative;
 z-index: 1;
}

.ham-open .b2 {
 transform: translateY(81.5px);
 width: 110px;
 position: relative;
 left: 60px;
 z-index: 0;
}

.ham-open .b3 {
 background-color: #ff4c4c;
 transform: translateY(63px);
 width: 140px;
 position: relative;
 left: 160px;
 z-index: 2;
}

.menu {
 display: flex;
 border-left: 8px solid #56ff47;
 flex-direction: column;
 background-color: #fff;
 margin-left: -700px;
 width: 292px;
 padding-top: 10px;
 padding-bottom: 10px;
 position: fixed;
 border-radius: 5px;
 top: 225px;
 transition: all .25s;
}

.menu a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: limegreen;
 font-family: 'Kumar One Outline';
 font-size: 2.3rem;
 text-align: center;
 margin-top: 12px;
 margin-bottom: 12px;
 transition: all .5s ease;
}

a:hover {
 color: #007001;
}

.info-wrap {
 flex-basis: 60%;
}

.info {
 font-family: 'Cedarville Cursive';
 color: white;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 4.5rem;
 text-align: center;
 margin-top: 60px;
}

.logo-wrap {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 flex-direction: column;
}

.logo-wrap div {
 font-family: 'Staatliches';
 color: white;
 font-size: 13rem;
 font-weight: bold;
 letter-spacing: 10px;
 margin-bottom: -5rem;
 position: relative;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;

}



/*------ABOUT------*/



.about-section {
 background-color: #35ad37;
}

.about-section h1 {
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 4.5rem;
 margin-top: 0;
 margin-bottom: 30px;
 padding-top: 15px;
 color: white;
 font-family: 'Cedarville Cursive';
 font-weight: bold;
}

.about-wrap {
 display: flex;
 padding-bottom: 80px;
}

.about-info, .image-slider-wrap {
 flex-basis: 50%;
}

.about-info p {
 color: white;
 font-family: 'Josefin Sans';
 font-size: 2rem;
 margin-left: 100px;
 margin-bottom: 0;
 margin-top: 0;
}

.image-slider {
 width: 650px;
 height: 400px;
 background-color: red;
 border-radius: 13px;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 position: relative;
}

.image-slider i {
 color: white;
 font-size: 5rem;
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 margin-top: -40px;
 transition: all .1s ease;
 cursor: pointer;
}

#left {
 transform: rotate(-90deg);
 left: -30px;
}

#right {
 transform: rotate(90deg);
 right: -30px;
}

#left:hover {
 transform: rotate(-90deg);
 transform: scale(1.3);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Mexican Restaurant</title>
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cedarville+Cursive|Josefin+Sans|Kumar+One+Outline|Staatliches" rel="stylesheet">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-oS3vJWv+0UjzBfQzYUhtDYW+Pj2yciDJxpsK1OYPAYjqT085Qq/1cq5FLXAZQ7Ay" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <header>
  <div class="header">
   <div class="nav-wrap">
    <div class="nav-box">
     <div class="b1"></div>
     <div class="b2"></div>
     <div class="b3"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="menu">
     <a href="#">Home</a>
     <a href="#">About</a>
     <a href="#">Menu</a>
     <a href="#">Contact</a>
     <a href="#">Location</a>
     <i class="fas fa-times" id="menu-close"></i>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="info-wrap">
    <p class="info">Authentic Mexican Food</p>

    <div class="logo-wrap">
     <div>YOUR</div>
     <div>LOGO</div>
     <div>HERE</div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </header>
 <main>
  <div class="about-section"> 
   <h1 class="about-h1">About Us</h1>

   <div class="about-wrap">
    <div class="about-info">
     <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestias voluptas pariatur consequuntur, repellat, laborum, rerum ipsum illo excepturi mollitia reprehenderit saepe nisi praesentium voluptate ab repellendus quos impedit, soluta natus dolore. Praesentium debitis odio cupiditate, reprehenderit alias. Sequi non beatae tempore fugit quia? Ratione aspernatur, quidem voluptates dignissimos Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloremque quo iure accusantium cupiditate hic, iste ab laborum incidunt neque a nihil, veritatis cumque quaerat, id laboriosam, labore eaque delectus perspiciatis.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="image-slider-wrap"> 
     <div class="image-slider">
      <i class="fas fa-sort-up" id="left"></i>
      <i class="fas fa-sort-up" id="right"></i>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </main>
 <footer>
  
 </footer>
</body>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/scrollreveal"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put both `transform` parameters in *one* line/rule, like this:

`transform: rotate(-90deg) scale(1.3);`

Otherwise they act as two rules, where the second rule overwrites the first one.

```js
const ham = document.querySelector('.nav-box');
const menu = document.querySelector('.menu');
const menuClose = document.querySelector('#menu-close');

ham.addEventListener('click', function() {
 ham.classList.add('ham-open');
 menu.style.marginLeft = '50px';
})

menuClose.addEventListener('click', function() {
 ham.classList.remove('ham-open');
 menu.style.marginLeft = '-700px';

})




window.sr = ScrollReveal();;

sr.reveal('.info', {
 duration: 2000,
 origin: 'bottom';
})
```

```css
html, body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

.header {
 background: url(img/mex-9.jpg);
 width: 100vw;
 height: 100vh;
 background-size: cover;
 background-attachment: fixed;
 background-position: center;
 display: flex;
}

.nav-wrap {
 flex-basis: 40%;
}

.nav-wrap i {
 color: white;
 font-size: 2rem;
 position: absolute;
 right: -33px;
 top: 0px;
 transition: all .1s ease;
}

.nav-wrap i:hover {
 cursor: pointer;
 transform: scale(1.15);
}

.nav-box {
 margin-left: 50px;
 margin-top: 100px;
 max-width: 70px;
 cursor: pointer;
 position: fixed;
}

.b1, .b2, .b3 {
 width: 70px;
 height: 8.5px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 background-color: #fff;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 transition: all .25s ease;
}

.b1 {
 background-color: #56ff47;
}

.b3 {
 background-color: #ff4c4c;
}

.ham-open .b1 {
 background-color: #56ff47;
 transform: translateY(100px);
 position: relative;
 z-index: 1;
}

.ham-open .b2 {
 transform: translateY(81.5px);
 width: 110px;
 position: relative;
 left: 60px;
 z-index: 0;
}

.ham-open .b3 {
 background-color: #ff4c4c;
 transform: translateY(63px);
 width: 140px;
 position: relative;
 left: 160px;
 z-index: 2;
}

.menu {
 display: flex;
 border-left: 8px solid #56ff47;
 flex-direction: column;
 background-color: #fff;
 margin-left: -700px;
 width: 292px;
 padding-top: 10px;
 padding-bottom: 10px;
 position: fixed;
 border-radius: 5px;
 top: 225px;
 transition: all .25s;
}

.menu a {
 text-decoration: none;
 color: limegreen;
 font-family: 'Kumar One Outline';
 font-size: 2.3rem;
 text-align: center;
 margin-top: 12px;
 margin-bottom: 12px;
 transition: all .5s ease;
}

a:hover {
 color: #007001;
}

.info-wrap {
 flex-basis: 60%;
}

.info {
 font-family: 'Cedarville Cursive';
 color: white;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 4.5rem;
 text-align: center;
 margin-top: 60px;
}

.logo-wrap {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 flex-direction: column;
}

.logo-wrap div {
 font-family: 'Staatliches';
 color: white;
 font-size: 13rem;
 font-weight: bold;
 letter-spacing: 10px;
 margin-bottom: -5rem;
 position: relative;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;

}



/*------ABOUT------*/



.about-section {
 background-color: #35ad37;
}

.about-section h1 {
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 4.5rem;
 margin-top: 0;
 margin-bottom: 30px;
 padding-top: 15px;
 color: white;
 font-family: 'Cedarville Cursive';
 font-weight: bold;
}

.about-wrap {
 display: flex;
 padding-bottom: 80px;
}

.about-info, .image-slider-wrap {
 flex-basis: 50%;
}

.about-info p {
 color: white;
 font-family: 'Josefin Sans';
 font-size: 2rem;
 margin-left: 100px;
 margin-bottom: 0;
 margin-top: 0;
}

.image-slider {
 width: 650px;
 height: 400px;
 background-color: red;
 border-radius: 13px;
 margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: auto;
 position: relative;
}

.image-slider i {
 color: white;
 font-size: 5rem;
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 margin-top: -40px;
 transition: all .1s ease;
 cursor: pointer;
}

#left {
 transform: rotate(-90deg);
 left: -30px;
}

#right {
 transform: rotate(90deg);
 right: -30px;
}

#left:hover {
 transform: rotate(-90deg) scale(1.3);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Mexican Restaurant</title>
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cedarville+Cursive|Josefin+Sans|Kumar+One+Outline|Staatliches" rel="stylesheet">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-oS3vJWv+0UjzBfQzYUhtDYW+Pj2yciDJxpsK1OYPAYjqT085Qq/1cq5FLXAZQ7Ay" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
 <header>
  <div class="header">
   <div class="nav-wrap">
    <div class="nav-box">
     <div class="b1"></div>
     <div class="b2"></div>
     <div class="b3"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="menu">
     <a href="#">Home</a>
     <a href="#">About</a>
     <a href="#">Menu</a>
     <a href="#">Contact</a>
     <a href="#">Location</a>
     <i class="fas fa-times" id="menu-close"></i>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="info-wrap">
    <p class="info">Authentic Mexican Food</p>

    <div class="logo-wrap">
     <div>YOUR</div>
     <div>LOGO</div>
     <div>HERE</div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </header>
 <main>
  <div class="about-section"> 
   <h1 class="about-h1">About Us</h1>

   <div class="about-wrap">
    <div class="about-info">
     <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestias voluptas pariatur consequuntur, repellat, laborum, rerum ipsum illo excepturi mollitia reprehenderit saepe nisi praesentium voluptate ab repellendus quos impedit, soluta natus dolore. Praesentium debitis odio cupiditate, reprehenderit alias. Sequi non beatae tempore fugit quia? Ratione aspernatur, quidem voluptates dignissimos Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloremque quo iure accusantium cupiditate hic, iste ab laborum incidunt neque a nihil, veritatis cumque quaerat, id laboriosam, labore eaque delectus perspiciatis.</p>
    </div>

    <div class="image-slider-wrap"> 
     <div class="image-slider">
      <i class="fas fa-sort-up" id="left"></i>
      <i class="fas fa-sort-up" id="right"></i>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </main>
 <footer>
  
 </footer>
</body>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/scrollreveal"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</html>
```